# Cancel a file upload in ng-file-upload

Tags: ng-file-upload

I have ng-file-upload with form submit running. I would like to add a button to cancel the upload after the user selects a file.
I have tried:

```
<button class= "btn btn-warning btn-cancel" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" 
          ng-click="cancelPic(picFile)">Cancel</button>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.cancelPic = function() {
        myForm.reset();
        file: '';
    }
```

The form does seem to reset as I get a "please select a file" message but the image remains - in the dev tools Elements:

```
<img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-src="!picFile.$error &amp;&amp; picFile" class="thumb" src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/85f1b27c-a92e-447d-b760-8cfe17bbd6b7" style="">
```

Obviously I'm barking up the wrong tree here. Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using? If you see the demo page, when you click on the file upload and select a file then click again and cancel the popup the image thumbnail will be removed too.

Comment: @danial I'm using 7.0.17 and yes in the demo it behaves like you say. I have a thumbnail displaying after file select and I would like a cancel button to remove that thumbnail and cancel the selected file. Clicking choose file again to cancel is not intuitive. I wish to emulate the functionality of the blueimp demo as far as the cancel button.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found what I sought at:
https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/12
The code that works is:

```
$scope.cancelPic = function(file) {
        myForm.reset();
        $scope.picFile = undefined;
    }
```

Now I need to apply this to individual images so a user can choose which to cancel and not reset the whole form. That's for another day.

Comment: If you set the file model value to null in a timeout it should clear the file I put and re validate the form.

Comment: @danial Could you look at my new question which is related to this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712299/deselecting-an-upload-file-causes-problems-with-files-indexing-in-ng-file-upload.                                     Could you also give an example of the timeout . Thanks